# JPanel.getWidth() is not accurate. Why?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I'm overriding a JPanel's `paintComponent()` method to draw some things on the screen.

This is what it looks like:

[image: JPanel]

I'm using the following code to set the clipping area. This is so that the edges can be curved.

```
RoundRectangle2D r = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 100, 150);
g.setClip(r);
```

---

Obviously, there is a problem with the right side of the window. Upon further inspection, I found that JPanel's `getWidth()` method is not reporting the correct figure. Usually, it's slightly off. For example:

```
Width = 500,  getWidth() = 492
Width = 1000, getWidth() = 992
Width = 100,  getWidth() = 192
Width = 350,  getWidth() = 342
Width = 600,  getWidth() = 592
```

My question is, **why is it so *consistently* wrong?** And why is `getHeight()` correct?

If there's no programmatic way to get the real width, should I simply add 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, be careful with clipping.  The repaint manager has already set the clipping rectangle when it passes it to your component and you could end up painting outside of the component (if you've created your own buffer, then knock yourself out).

Component sizes are 0 based, that means the the width you want is `getWidth() - 1`

This is the same concept as collections and arrays.

Also, while I'm here, you're assuming that the window size (say 500) will wrap around you component.  It's the other way around.  A window of size 500 will produce components smaller then that, because of the window border.

Comment: thanks for this. What do you mean when you ask if I've created my own buffer?

Comment: If you are creating a `BufferedImage` inside the `paintComponent` method and using the `BufferedImage`'s graphics context.  If not, you really, really, really need to be careful altering the graphics clipping

Comment: Hmm.. assuming that this JPanel contains no components, and I'm simply using its graphics context as a canvas, then what harm can I cause?

Comment: The problem occurs only if you make the clipping rectangle larger then the component.  This would allow you to paint out side what is visually available.  I'm not saying not to, I'm just saying to be careful ;) - Personally, I'd create a `BufferedImage` and paint to that, then paint the result to the component, but that's just me.

Comment: The actual width of a component is still `getWidth()`, just like the length of an array is `length` - it's just that the first pixel has `0` offset while the last one has `getWidth() - 1`.

Comment: @JacobRaihle that's what it was "trying" to say, I see your point and will update my post. Thanks

Comment: Well, the constructor takes the width and height of the rectangle to create, so passing `getWidth()` should be correct. I'm not familiar with clipping rects, are they in relation to the root pane? That could cause problems if you give it 0s...

Comment: @JacobRaihle "so passing getWidth() should work" - no it won't. It'd be like saying use List.size() to get the last element from a list. The width of the drawable surface is 0-getWidth() - 1. For your example to work, the first renderable position would have to be 1x1

Comment: If you want a 1x1 rectangle, you would pass `(0, 0, 1, 1)`, not `(0, 0, 0, 0)`. `0, 0` will still be the only drawable pixel though. If you want to manually move elements from an array to an `ArrayList`, you would set the initial capacity to `array.length`, not `array.length-1`, but `array.length-1` would still be the last position.

Comment: @JacobRaihle - Yes, you're correct on that point, but renderable width is still only width - 1 (starting at 0) - I think we're saying the same thing, just differently :P

Comment: Perhaps. We certainly aren't being very productive :P

Comment: @JacobRaihle yeah, but it was fun :D (sorry long day, come home to screaming 4 month old - doesn't do much for ones cognitive processes :P)